# Call Child Function from Parent in Reactjs using useRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-ref

The Code is written using React Functional components.

Upon clicking button in parent, the function showAlert should be fired. That is the requirement.

Currently in the parent component **childRef.current** is not able to call **showAlert()** function.  I get a typescript error

> `Property 'showAlert' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<RefAttributes<unknown>>'`

Parent Functional component Code

```
import React, { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';
export default function App() {
  const childRef = useRef<typeof Child>(Child);
  return (
    <div className="container">

      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => { childRef.current.showAlert() }}
      >
        Call Function
            </button>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Child Functional component

```
import React, { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(
        ref,
        () => ({
             showAlert() {
                alert("Child Function Called")
                console.log('hello world')
            }
        }),
    )
    return (
        <div>Child Component</div>
    )
})

export default Child
```

Comment: You're almost there but there are some typescript types that you need to fill in on the Child.  I can write an answer.

Comment: @LindaPaiste could you please write the answer. It would be really helpful

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've got this almost right, but `typeof Child` is not giving you an accurate type because the `Child` component itself is not typed strictly enough.  It's getting inferred as `forwardRef<unknown, {}>`.  We need to specificity the type of the forwarded ref in order for this to work.

We can define an interface for the ref that we want:

```
interface CanShowAlert {
  showAlert(): void;
}
```

We set the two generics on the `forwardRef` function for `Child`.  `CanShowAlert` is the ref type and `{}` is the props type:

```
const Child = forwardRef<CanShowAlert, {}>((props, ref) => {
```

We use the same generic on the `useRef`:

```
const childRef = useRef<CanShowAlert>(null);
```

You get an error with your initial value `useRef<CanShowAlert>(Child)` because the ref is for an *instance* of the component, but you are passing in the component function itself.  Instead we use `null` as the initial value.

The `current` property of the ref will either be a component instance or `null`, so we need to make sure that it's not `null` before we call the `showAlert` function.  We can use the optional chaining operator `?.` for that.

```
childRef.current?.showAlert()
```

Complete code:

```
import React, {forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle} from "react";

interface CanShowAlert {
  showAlert(): void;
}

export default function App() {
  const childRef = useRef<CanShowAlert>(null);
  return (
    <div className="container">

      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => { childRef.current?.showAlert() }}
      >
        Call Function
            </button>
      
    </div>
  )
}


const Child = forwardRef<CanShowAlert, {}>((props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(
        ref,
        () => ({
             showAlert() {
                alert("Child Function Called")
                console.log('hello world')
            }
        }),
    )
    return (
        <div>Child Component</div>
    )
})
```

Comment: OMG, this is great! Exactly what I've been looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
useImperativeHandle(
        ref,
        () => ({
             showAlert: () => { // like this here
                alert("Child Function Called")
                console.log('hello world')
            }
        }),
)
```

Comment: It says `Property 'showAlert' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<RefAttributes<unknown>>'`

Is the Declaration of useRef wrong here ?